# Do not want to highlight tab by default

Tags: android, tabs, tabwidget

I have a layout with image and listview. Below them i need to add tabs.
When i used tab widget it is highlighted first tab and displaying that tab activity result below the tabs.
So i have to stop the activity of the first tab. When clicking on tab only the activity should be called and it should go to another screen.

Below is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
    android:background="@drawable/banner" 
    android:layout_width="323dp" 
    android:layout_height="100dp"></ImageView>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="28dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <ImageView android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:onClick="mapfunction" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:src="@drawable/map1" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView3" android:src="@drawable/listtab" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"></ImageView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:text="LIST" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_marginRight="14dp"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:text="MAP" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="31dp"></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@id/ListView01"  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="253dp"></ListView>
    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="44dp">
          <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="34dp"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is my activity code for displaying the tabs.

```
Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Contacts.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("places").setIndicator("PLACES",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.places))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Contacts.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("camera").setIndicator("CAMERA",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.camera))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Comment: What is it doing and what do you want it to do?  It's doing x, but I want it to do y.  I cannot parse that from your question above.

Comment: My question is simple i don't want to highlight the tab by default

Comment: By highlight, do you mean that it shouldn't show any pages by default (then what should happen)? Or that it is colored orange (or whatever color your skin uses)?

Comment: I have page by default, in this page i need to show the tabs below the content, and moreover i don't want to highlight any tab

Answer (score 1):

If you never want the current tab highlighted then you can simply set the 2 graphics the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_files_white"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_files_white" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Can you give me sample code for this as i don't have knowledge on this because i am new to android

Comment: There's no code involved.  Just set your @drawables to teh same graphic: "@drawable/ic_tab_files_white" for both the regular and the selected graphic.

Comment: OK i will do that, but how can i stop the activity of the tab

Comment: The TabHost used to have an odd behavior.  No matter what you did the 1st tab's activity was always executed.  A workaround is to create your first tab with an empty activity and set it to not visible.  You might play around with this idea to get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Simply dont set the current tab in your activity

`tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);`